# Angular: autocomplete field changes focus after removing an item

Tags: javascript, css, angular, autocomplete, primeng

I have an Angular 2 app that uses PrimeNG components.

The UI has autocomplete component with multi-select (`p-autoComplete`) similar to the one from [the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete):

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="countries" 
                [suggestions]="filteredCountriesMultiple" 
                (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultiple($event)" 
                [minLength]="1" 
                placeholder="Countries" 
                field="name" 
                [multiple]="true">
</p-autoComplete>
```

The only difference is that in my case the input field has fixed dimensions and scroll bar.

**Problem:**

Every time when I remove an element from the middle of the autocomplete list it moves focus to the bottom of the input field. It looks like this:

[image]

It is very annoying for users, especially when there are several fields that should be removed.

**Question:** How to force scroll to stay on the same position after removing an element?

**How to reproduce:**

To be more specific, you can reproduce the issue by adding the next css

```
max-width: 150px;
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

directly on the [documentation page](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) into `ui-autocomplete-multiple-container.ui-inputtext` css class using browser console.

**UPDATE:**
I managed to get the scroller position by setting up `onUnselect` method in the component using code like this:

```
onUnselect(event: any) {
    document.querySelector("div.my-input-class").scrollTop
}
```

**UPDATE 2: I managed to make it work**

The solution is combination of `onUnselect` and `onFocus` event handlers.

First. I save the last scroller position into a field in `onUnselect` call.

Second. I set this value to the specified element during `onFocus` call.

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
scrollPosition: number = 0;

onUnselect(event: any) {
    let input = document.querySelector("div.my-input-class");
    this.scrollPosition = input.scrollTop;
}

onFocus(event: any) {
    let input = document.querySelector("div.my-input-class");
    input.scrollTop = this.scrollPosition;
}
```

It works well and probably this will be the final solution.

However I don't like it. It would be much better if PrimeNG guys embed such a useful functionality in their component. For me it is strange why doesn't it come out of the box.

**If you find better solution please propose.**

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce?

Comment: It seems like the cursor is causing the jumping behavior. So i would recommend trying to either disable the cursor when an item is removed (maybe by disabling the element) or try switching the focus to some other element before removing the item. I don't know if the control you're using will let you do that but i cannot test it until i get access to a computer

Comment: Also, this is one of the best structured questions i've seen. It was really easy to see/understand your problem. Thanks for putting in the time and effort on it!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `onFocus` event to handle the same as below,

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="countries" 
                [suggestions]="filteredCountriesMultiple"                     
                (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultiple($event)" 
                styleClass="width12" (onFocus)="onFocus($event)">

  ....


onFocus(event){
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);

}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XBGXe8kvD3Q861zK1Vwe?p=preview)**

Comment: May be I'm doing something wrong, but I tried and it does not work. And the demo does not have any scrollbar so there is no way to check it. Anyway I didn't understand how could setting up window`s property influence on scroll bar inside particular page element? In my case I need to set position of the scroller inside input element, not the one from the page.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota reduce the window size and test.

Comment: Now I get what you mean. May be the question is not completely clear - I need to control scroller on the input element, not the one from window. The code you proposed changes scroller position of the window.

Comment: You can use it for the `element` too. Use `event.srcElement.scroll....` exact object I'm not sure. Do a console log and walkthrough. I'm in mobile site. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you. This call gets reflected, I'll try to calculate correct scroller position.

Answer (score 1):

```
onUnselect(event: any) {
    // get index of the removed element
    // get total options count
    // get height of the element that contains the options
    // divide the height by number of options
    // set scroll potion to the result of division multiplied by the index
   document.querySelector('.ui-autocomplete-multiple-container.ui-inputtext').scrollTop = calculatedValue; 
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you propose to set scroll position? I get the element and set its `scrollTop` and it does not work even without calculations. Let's say I set `scrollTop` of the element to 100 - the scroll jumps to the bottom just like before.

Comment: This is exactly what I've just explained in my comment, I tried this way and it does not work :(

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing anything. I just pasted this code on the documentation link you sent and it worked for me

Comment: Try wrapping it inside a setTimeout call and play with the delay starting with 0

Comment: How did you inject your code into that page? Or you tried to call it once without `onUnselect ` relation?

Comment: Yes without onUnselect. If you have a fiddle, then share please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151166/discussion-between-oleksandr-shpota-and-lucky-soni).